# The minimum value of the sum of squares of the elements of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

For $D = diag(d_1, d_2, .., d_n)$ a real diagonal $n \times n$ matrix and  $X$ a real $n \times n, rank(X) = 1$ matrix define
$$F_D(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} (d_{ij} - x_{ij})^{2}.$$
Find the minimum of $F_D(X)$.

Comment: As $X$ is rank one, it holds $X=vw^\top$. Now, with this, try to solve $\nabla G(v,w)=0$ with $G(v,w)=F(vw^\top)$.

Comment: What are your variables, both $D$ and $X$? In this case, the minimum is zero: the diagonal matrix ${\rm diag}([1,0,...,0])$ has rank one.

Comment: @Florian $D$ is fixed, $X$ can be any real matrix with rank one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for the best rank-one approximation of a given (diagonal) matrix in the Frobenius norm sense. This is solved by the [Eckart-Young Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem), which tells you that you should use a truncated singular value decomposition, i.e., $X$ is given by $\sigma \cdot u \cdot v^{\rm T}$, where $\sigma$, $u$, and $v$ represent the dominant singular value, left singular vector, and right singular vector, respectively.

In the special case of a diagonal matrix, this solution can be further simplified: as long as the $d_i$ are distinct, the best rank-one approximation is the diagonal matrix that has the largest of the $d_i$'s in the appropriate place and zeros everywhere. The minimum value of $F_d(X)$ is then $\sum_{j\neq i} d_j^2$ where $i = \arg \max_i d_i$.

Comment: I do not think this question should have been answered as the OP showed zero work of their own.